# Longer boot time after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, 19.10

After upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10, I noticed an increased boot time, as well as a strange graphic issue: between the splash screen and the login screen, I have a black screen with a blinking `_`. This screen lasts for more than 1 minute and reacts to keystrokes: I can type in here, even though it doesn't do anything.

end of dmesg:

```
[   10.767817] wlo1: associated
[   11.829939] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   19.465736] random: crng init done
[   19.465742] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[  116.212968] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  138.839629] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  139.737489] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  139.737548] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  139.737561] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  145.316271] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

I'm not sure if this is related, but there is a huge gap between random and rfkill.

`systemd-analyze blame` (excluding <1s):

```
1min 42.198s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     10.306s gdm.service
      7.850s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.535s dev-sda5.device
      2.500s snapd.service
      2.171s e2scrub_reap.service
      1.676s upower.service
      1.666s dev-loop10.device
      1.660s systemd-logind.service
      1.656s dev-loop18.device
      1.647s dev-loop16.device
      1.640s dev-loop12.device
      1.637s dev-loop14.device
      1.634s dev-loop19.device
      1.634s dev-loop13.device
      1.631s dev-loop11.device
      1.615s dev-loop9.device
      1.614s dev-loop15.device
      1.612s dev-loop8.device
      1.596s dev-loop17.device
      1.513s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.179s dev-loop0.device
      1.177s dev-loop2.device
      1.158s dev-loop1.device
      1.133s dev-loop3.device
      1.103s systemd-resolved.service
      1.094s dev-loop4.device
      1.068s systemd-timesyncd.service
      1.065s dev-loop5.device
      1.055s dev-loop7.device
      1.045s systemd-journald.service
```

Any clue on what's going on?

Comment: I have same problem on ubuntu 20.04, did you found a solution already?

Comment: I had an old desktop, also running ubuntu. Normally, I only use LTS releases, but for fun, I upgraded to the newest version of Ubuntu. The login was hard to come through, and the graphics were a bit weird. So then I did a clean install, and it was ok again. I don't have a clue what is going on with that log, but maybe a clean install will help you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the nefarious `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` process, which is seen doing things with those `rfkill` entries in the log. So long as this machine is not being used as a server — which is likely isn't if it's running a non-LTS version of Ubuntu Desktop — then you can disable this without consequence.

Here's how you do it:

0. Open a terminal (if not already open)
1. Disable the service:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
   $ sudo systemctl mask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
   ```
2. Reboot

The first command disables the service. The second one ensures it does not get re-activated at boot.

The purpose of this service is to make sure that the network is connected and active before continuing the boot process. If you do not need your system to be accessed by other computers on the network *before you log in*, then it can safely be disabled. The network will continue to come online as expected, but without a service sitting there waiting for it to finish.

Hope this resolves your issue.

---

***Note:** If you would ever like to restore the service, you can do so by unmasking and then enabling* `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` *like this:*

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
$ sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: That solution didn't solve the problem. dmesg still looks like that: ```[   10.241930] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready
[   99.227473] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  104.802458] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  106.873852] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Comment: One other possible venue to explore would involve a possible "stale" swap record. Can you update your question to include the output of: `sudo lsblk -af | grep -sv loop` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`? That second command may fail if you do not have that file, which is fine.

Comment: NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat           8F42-8514                             503,2M     2% /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4           bded3905-fad6-4f96-9445-61fb957e267e  799,5G    11% /

Comment: It's not exactly my question but i have same problem. So i cant update question. Btw. second command did fail

Comment: Ah, that's right. It's not your question. Not sure why I didn't catch that sooner. Either way, I can see from the `lsblk` result that there shouldn't be any stale swap records getting in the way of the boot speeds. Will need to dig deeper into the startup process to see where else delays can take place.

Comment: I would really appreciate your help. I'm kinda stuck with that I did try everything that i found on google and still no solution :/

Comment: `lsmod | grep wmi` please. and `sudo dmidecode -t 0` also `lsusb | grep -i blue` please.

Comment: @nobody I did answered to your comment in the answer to the question. It should be easier with output of commands you posted here

Answer (score 0):

It's answer to @nobody comment. Since I'm not the author it should be easier in this way

```
lsmod | grep wmi

snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd                    90112  33 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi


sudo dmidecode -t 0

# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: P1.40
    Release Date: 12/06/2016
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.12


lsusb | grep -i blue
returned empty
```